# Solving modulo Equation with denominator

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I am having the following equation    $\frac{a}{10} \pmod{n}$= 7(mod n) , where n is prime number and is known we have to find out the value of `a` ? How to solve this ?

For equation of form  ${10*a}\pmod{n}$= 7(mod n) , i  just need to find out the modulo inverse of 10 and multiply it with both side.. but how to solve the above one ?

what if `a` is in the form of `x^y` where x is an integer and is known we have to find out y ?

Answer (score 3):

You have if I understand you correctly, $a/10\equiv 7\pmod n$.
The solution to this is surely $a\equiv70\pmod n$.

Comment: I have edited the question...